# Find the limit if it exists. Multivariable calculus

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to (4,0)}y^2\cos\left({1\over(x-4)^2+y^2}\right) $$

I am having trouble evaluating this limit. If somebody could help me, that would be awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Hint: $\left | y^2cos\left({1\over(x-4)^2+y^2}\right)\right|\le y^2$

Answer (score 4):

The limit is 0 since $cos$ is bounded by 1 in modulus.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is $0$.

**Hint:**
$$x-4=r\cos\theta$$
$$y=r\sin\theta$$

Apply for $r\rightarrow 0$